# Powershell to set user-agent string IE

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, scripting, user-agent

I'm using Powershell to control IE in a script, and want to change the user agent string for certain parts of the script, then change it back to the starting value. I could not find any way to do this that did not involve editing some files at the byte level (not comfortable with that). any advice?

Comment: pretty sure its not possible with ie (programatically) but for example with the .net webclient or `invoke-webrequest` you can specify the user-agent, maybe thats an alternative for you

Comment: Doesn't work, as I'm using powershell to control internet explorer (I need to interact with the page) but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 64bit userAgent strings are stored under the WOW64 node in the registry.....you have to make your customizations to the UAS tokens in both places....

If you are deploying a 32bit ActiveX, you have to rebuild it for both x86 and x64 platforms. The web install project you use from Visual Studio should create UAS tokens for both platforms.

using UAS sniffing on client web pages or on server side browsercaps is frowned upon and unreliable as MSIE browsers and the others allow developers to change it from the Developer tool.

MSIE's browser version emulation.. eg. Compatibility View sends a naked UAS to the server (no plugins tokens)

go to http://winware.org/en or http://enhanceie.com to test which userAgent string is being used by your IE version and what is sent to the server... (browsercaps tests).